# How to extract image file details in Python (Windows)?

Tags: python, windows

I'm writing a program that has to process multiple images. Many of them have different resolutions (dpi). Is there a way to retrieve the information from file properties? I tried PIL.ExifTags, PIL.IptcImagePlugin, other EXIF extractors, but everything returns None.[image: the information I need to retrieve]

Comment: What format do those images have?

Comment: The batch that I have now has JPG mostly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it can't get dpi from jpeg by exif tools, the jpeg may not have exif and may have JFIF(APP0 metadata). It can get dpi from JFIF.

```
def get_resolution(filename):
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        data = f.read()
    if data[0:2] != b"\xff\xd8":
        raise ValueError("Not JPEG.")
    if data[2:4] != b"\xff\xe0":
        return None
    else:
        if data[13] == b"\x00":
            unit = "no unit"
        elif data[13] == b"\x01":
            unit = "dpi"
        elif data[13] == b"\x02":
            unit = "dpcm"
        else:
            raise ValueError("Bad JFIF")
        x = 256 * ord(data[14]) + ord(data[15])
        y = 256 * ord(data[16]) + ord(data[17])
    return {"unit":unit, "resolution":(x, y)}
```

Comment: I tried it and it works, although partially. There are files which have the resolution in properties, but the script says it's 1 dpi or not Jpeg. it seems that I have to further look into JFIF description.

Comment: "it's 1 dpi" - When returned value is _{'resolution': (1, 1), 'unit': 'no unit'}_, It seems Windows automatically set dpi value to 96. 96 would be default dpi value on Windows.     "script says not Jpeg" - This function checks magic number to find jpeg. JFIF is jpeg metadata. Not for png, gif, and more...